# Check last row every iteration in a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code :

```
 For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & LastCompoundInterval)
        LastTransaction = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If <some condition>
        ...
        If <some condition>
        ...
        End If
        Range("H" & LastTransaction) = DateAdd("m", m, cell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        Range("I" & LastTransaction) = 0
        End If
Next cell
```

I am appending values to the end of the `H` and `I` columns, which have the same number of rows, but the `LastTransaction` variable for the last row remains the same each iteration. Shouldn't it update every iteration?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the answer to your question *Shouldn't it update every iteration?* is Yes. It updates *LastTransaction* but it just stays the same.

You need to re-calculate lastrow like before the next like that if you want to go to the next row.

```
 LastTransaction = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Maybe you also need to add a +1 here if you want to have the first empty cell in column H
 For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & LastCompoundInterval)
        ' LastTransaction = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If <some condition>
        ...
        If <some condition>
        ...
        End If
        Range("H" & LastTransaction) = DateAdd("m", m, cell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        Range("I" & LastTransaction) = 0
        End If
        LastTransaction = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row +1
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

`LastTransaction` comes from `Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. It will get the row number of the last non-blank cell in H column.

`Rows.Count` here means the total row count in the active worksheet, which is a constant. The whole expression is identical to the following manual operation:

- locate the last cell (with largest row number) in H column
- search for the next non-blank cell upward by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up arrow</kbd>
- return that cell's row number

Comment: This only answers 'why the variable remains the same'. While I was still trying to figure out what the definition of 'last row in each iteration' and 'appending' mean, I see @JMP's answer. You can refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be:

```
 For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & LastCompoundInterval)
        LastTransaction = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If <some condition>
        ...
        If <some condition>
        ...
        End If
        Range("H" & LastTransaction + 1) = DateAdd("m", m, cell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        Range("I" & LastTransaction + 1) = 0
        End If
Next cell
```

Previously it only overwrote the value of the last row in the columns, and didn't add another value as another row. `+ 1` makes the new entry on the next available row.